# Create a string containing quotes without escaping

Tags: swift, swift3

need to send a json string that contains quotes:

```
"{"property1": false, "property2": "orange"}"
```

but when I mount that string the return I have contains \" instead of only ":

```
"{\"property1\": false, \"property2\": \"orange\"}"
```

this is a problem because I'm sending that string to be processed by a server. How can I send this string without the escape characters "\" ?

Comment: as I can see it is not a string, it is a JSON (quite similar, but not identical in computer point of view) so if you parse your JSON in your server, escape character should not be a problem

Comment: please add your code send json to server

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry. The backslashes are virtual, they are added to be able to display double quotes in a literal string.

These lines convert the dictionary to JSON and prints the raw data. A backslash is `0x5c`, a double quote `0x22`.

As you can see there is no backslash in the data.

```
let dict : [String:Any] = ["property1": false, "property2": "orange"]
let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
print(data as NSData)
// <7b227072 6f706572 74793222 3a226f72 616e6765 222c2270 726f7065 72747931 223a6661 6c73657d>
```

When `print`ing the string in a Playground you see

[image]